# Expected the operants to be of similar type or any Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I got this issue where i cannot find the solution[image]

As I saw `router: Router` and `router.url: string`. So I can't find any explanation why it's complaining in html when `router.url === '/successlogin'`. Any idea?

Update: I changed type of router, `router.url: String` and it's ok now but I think it should work the opposite. Why is this happening? Until now I thought type `string` was the "right" one and not `String`...

My code simplified:

HTML

```
<div *ngIf="!global.showUnauthorizedMessage || router.url === '/successlogin'" class="beforeFooter"></div>
 <div *ngIf="!global.showUnauthorizedMessage || router.url ==='/successlogin'" id="footer">
```

Component

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
constructor( public router: Router) { code here }
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you have `Router` injected in your component's constructor? Does the error change (assuming you have it injected) if you make it `public` instead of `private`? Your statement should work without error https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4e64me. Can you show your component code please?

Comment: CODEEEEEEEEE. No code, no answer.

Comment: Where/how are you doing `Router.url: string`? Also please show the import for `Router`.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky the thing here is that when I change the type in `router.d.ts` into `String` the warning disappears.

Answer (score 13):

This message is from the "Angular Language Service" extension in VSCode !

Probably an update because before I didn't have this message....

2 solutions I found is to use `localeCompare()` like this:

```
router.url.localeCompare('/successLogin')===0
```

or

use `String` instead of `string`

Comment: Any luck silencing those stupid messages? I need that extension but my OCD can't stand those false positives.. Changing the code is not an option..

Answer (score 4):

Quick fix for this :

a) store"/successlogin" in some variable and do comparison with that variable

Component

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export class someComponent {

successLogin = '/successlogin'; 

constructor( public router: Router) { code here }
}
```

Html

```
<div *ngIf="!global.showUnauthorizedMessage || router.url === successLogin" class="beforeFooter"></div>
 <div *ngIf="!global.showUnauthorizedMessage || router.url === successLogin" id="footer">
```

**Note** since this seems to be a path, ideally it should be read from a constant file, for maintainability perspective.

Cheers (y)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. I changed the type from `String` to `string` and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

some times it comes from using;

```
*ngIf="!somevalvar === somevar"
```

instead use :

```
*ngIf="somevalvar !== somevar"
```